# Is the gyroscopic effect created by high rpm turbo-pumps an issue for rocket attitude control?

Tags: rockets, attitude

Is the gyro effect taken into consideration in the control strategy or is it somehow mitigated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This [paper](https://www.spacefoundation.org/sites/default/files/tech-track-papers/Paper%20Moroz%2C%20Leonid%20-%20Development%20of%20Highly%20Competitive%20Liquid%20Rocket%20Engines%20in%20Time%20of%20Space%20Gold%20Rush_0.pdf) states

> The  reactive  momentum  of  rotor  rotation  influences  the  control  of  trajectory. Therefore this parameter should be
> accounted for during the rocket engine layout determination.
>
> .......
>
> For  the  small  rockets  that  do  not  have  active  stabilization
> controls,the  value  of  gyroscopic momentum  has  a  significant
> influence  obstructing  the  rocket  turn.  For  the  large
> rockets ,the  influence  of gyroscopic momentum is not significant.